# Cannot get swfobject 2.3.2 working on Firefox, Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, flash, swfobject

I am trying to upgrade my site from using swfobject 1.5 to 2.3.2 (latest version), I am unable to get the video to play in Firefox, Chrome, or Safari on Mac.  The placeholder is replaced with the outline of the player, but if I right-click in the player region, I get the message: "Movie not loaded...".  I have drawn from various examples from the web which all seem pretty straightforward and seem to agree.

I believe the path is valid, as all examples I have seen showed the movie file path to be relative to the hosting page (not relative to the placement of the swfobject.js file, as was with v1.5).  In any event, I believe the path is valid for if I use an invalid path, space is not made for the player.  I have even tried using an absolute URL.  The file itself is also valid, as I can play it without any problem using swfobject v1.5.

I also have tried putting the javascript code in both the head, and also directly under the mediaspace (not simultaneously) but the results are exactly the same.

Here is the embed code:

Javascript (in head):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../media/flash/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  swfobject.embedSWF('../media/video/jewels.mp4', 'mediaspace_jewels', '400', '326', '10.0.0');
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div style="text-align:center; width: 640px; margin: 30px auto;" id="jewels_video_container">
  <p id="mediaspace_jewels">-- Something went wrong --</p>
</div>
```

If I examine the generated code in Firefox inspector, it shows:

```
<object style="visibility: visible;" data="../media/video/jewels.mp4" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="mediaspace_jewels" height="326" width="400"></object>
```

EDIT:

One thing I'm a little confused about, is I have not found an indication of how I reference the player I am using (JWPlayer).  In v1.5 it was passed as the first argument in the SWFObject constructor.

EDIT2:

Here is an example:
http://kevinallasso.org/flashexample/html/psychotic.html

The directory structure is exposed for examination.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to embed an MP4 file. SWFObject only embeds SWFs, you'd then need to have a SWF file that loads your MP4 (such as JWPlayer).

JWPlayer has its own embed code, you don't need to use SWFObject. Also, JWPlayer supports HTML5 playback of MP4s, so Flash wouldn't even be required (but would be available as a fallback for older browsers). https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406723

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know, and JWPlayer makes embedding pretty simple, and the fact that v6 and v7 give full HTML5 support (write `video` tags) is pretty appealing.  The only problem for me is that the JWPlayer versions that give HTML5 support (don't write `embed` tags) cannot be used offline, which is something I need, and the lower versions, which I feel are more private, require external embed code (such as SWFobject).

Answer (score 0):

As pipwerks pointed out, arg[0] for `swfobject.embedSWF` is data, not the movie file, so the Flash player .swf needs to go there (such as JWPlayer).  So then how do we get it to play an mp4?  How do we tell it what file to play?  arg[6] takes `flashvars` as an object, and thus the filename can be entered as the `file` property, poster image as the `image` property.  arg[7] takes `params` as an object.

In essence our code becomes something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var params = {
    allowfullscreen: "true",
    allowscriptaccess: "always"
  };
  var flashvars = {
    file: "my_video.mp4",
    image: "video/my_video_poster.jpg"
  };
  swfobject.embedSWF("video/player.swf",
                     "demo_video_flash",
                     "400",
                     "326",
                     "10.0.0",
                     "video/expressInstall.swf",
                     flashvars,
                     params);
</script>
```

The arguments are as follows:

0) location of Flash player swf 
1) ID of the element that will be replaced by the player
2) width of video
3) height of video
4) Lowest version of Flash allowed
5) expressInstall.swf - Adobe prompt if version is out of date (see below)
6) flashvars
7) params

The generated code becomes:

```
<object style="visibility: visible;" data="flash/player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="demo_video_flash" height="326" width="400">
  <param value="true" name="allowfullscreen" />
  <param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess" />
  <param value="file=my_video.mp4&image=video/my_video_poster.jpg" name="flashvars">
</object>
```

Note that, like SWFObject 1.5, the `file` property (filename of our movie) is relative to the location of the flash player, and the `image` property (poster image) is relative to the HTML file.

arg[5], the "expressInstall.swf" argument, points to a flash file which will trigger a prompt to the user to update their Flash version if it is out of date.  More on express install: http://learnswfobject.com/the-basics/adobes-express-install/

`swfobject.embedSWF` actually takes 10 arguments; I don't know what the last 2 are.

As a side note:

While SWFObject 2.3 was updated to give HTML5 support, and also no longer uses `<embed>` tags but `<object>` tags instead (see 2nd link below for rationale), it is a Flash embedding tool and not a video embedding tool, and thus does not provide standalone "HTML5 with Flash fallback" support (ie, it will not write `<video>` tags), as does the embedding code that comes with JWPlayer 6 and 7 and others.  HTML5 video support will have to be handled explicitly, as shown in this article:  http://henriksjokvist.net/archive/2009/2/using-the-html5-video-tag-with-a-flash-fallback/.
See also: https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject/wiki/SWFObject-and-HTML5.

SWFObject does have an advantage however in that it can be used offline, and also that no data is sent to any entity, if that is a concern.  Some players which offer full HTML5 support can only be used online (eg, JWPlayer's full support versions).

Comment: SWFObject has no relation to video, it is unfair to say it doesn't support video, as it was never intended to. All SWFObject does is embed a SWF (not video) by writing an `<object>` to the HTML file. SWFObject is not a video-embedding tool.

Comment: @pipwerks: Edited my answer to clarify SWFObject's function.